# Can other Chrome extensions read the log messages written by my extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've written an extension for Google Chrome which writes something to the console of its background page via `console.log`. Can any other extension access the data I've written there, or is it safe from them?

I'm guessing the answer is "no other extension can access this, only your extension (and the user)"; but I was not able to find an authoritative source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With default flags, the browser will deny (silent) access to `chrome-extension://` pages to other extensions/apps with public API.

There are flags that can override this (e.g. `silent-debugger-extension-api` flag with `chrome.debugger` API), but it will require actions from the user (or a local attack that can change the Chrome launcher parameters).

Also, there are private APIs that allow things like [Chrome Apps & Extensions Developer Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-apps-extensions-de/ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc) to function, but as a private API only apps whitelisted by Google have access.

Lastly, [extensions that extend DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) can potentially divert the console output as long as DevTools is open by replacing the `console` object with a malicious copy. It's very unlikely, and I have not tested that, but it's theoretically possible.